# TestNG Parameter not recognizing String Parameter

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to run a Selenium script with the option of running it using a chrome or headless driver. This may not be the correct way of implementing this but it was the first idea I had. The solution may be to avoid this completely...

In the setup method I am using the TestNG parameters to define what environment I want the test to run in and also what driver I want to use. The @Optional tag is used to define a default value when one is not provided.

```
public class Test1 {

@Parameters({"envDomain","driverName"})
@BeforeTest
public void setUp(@Optional("alpha1")String envDomain, @Optional("chrome")String driverName) {
    PropertiesCollection.selectDriver(driverName);
    PropertiesCollection.env_domain = envDomain;
}
```

The PropertiesCollection.selectDriver() method is taking a string name to decide what to set the driver to.

```
public class PropertiesCollection {
public static WebDriver driver;
public static WebDriverWait wait;
public static String env_domain;

public static void selectDriver(String driverName) {

    if (driverName == "chrome") {
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath + "\\configs\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        PropertiesCollection.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    if (driverName == "headless") {
        PropertiesCollection.driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    }

}
```

The driver is failing to be set in the first if statement. When I manually enter the String "chrome" it seems to work as expected. I am not sure why it is not working while using the "chrome" from TestNG. When I run it through the debugger it looks like driverName is set to "chrome" but the if statement is still being skipped.

Example that works:

```
public class Test1 {

@Parameters({"envDomain"})
@BeforeTest
public void setUp(@Optional("alpha1")String envDomain) {
    PropertiesCollection.selectDriver("chrome");
    PropertiesCollection.env_domain = envDomain;
}
```

The envDomain tag is also working as expected so I am not sure why the driverName parameter would work a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able resolve my issue by changing the conditional in the if statement.

```
public class PropertiesCollection {
public static WebDriver driver;
public static WebDriverWait wait;
public static String env_domain;

public static void selectDriver(String driverName) {

    if (driverName.equals("chrome")) {
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath + "\\configs\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        PropertiesCollection.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    if (driverName.equals("headless")) {
        PropertiesCollection.driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    }

}
```

Someone else might be able to explain in more depth why this works and why the original doesn't. But I am guessing it has something to do with asking if the parameter is equal to the object itself or if it is equal to the string value...